# Could Flint's powers reassemble the Earth?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield, inhumans

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* season 5, we meet Flint in the year 2091. He undergoes Terrigenesis and gains the power to manipulate and move rocks, so he can not only *move* them around but also *change their structure*. In addition, the Earth has been destroyed in that timeline. With all this in mind, could Flint reassemble the Earth from its broken pieces and recreate the Earth?

Comment: It was heavily implied in the ending shots of his arc that that was exactly what he was going to attempt.